# How to connect to Postgres Cloud Sql without public IP from Cloud Run

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

There is a documentation on the Cloud SQL for Cloud Run connection(https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-run), but it contains the following line:

> Note: These instructions require your Cloud SQL instance to have a
>   public IP address configured.

Is there any way to use Postgres Cloud SQL from Cloud Run if Cloud SQL does not expose public IP address(uses private ip)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Connecting to Cloud SQL from Cloud Run page](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-run), states and I quote verbatim "Note: These instructions require your Cloud SQL instance to have a public IP address configured."

Private IP access is done so via a [Virtual Private Cloud (VPC)](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/), in order to access your instance through a VPC, the resource you are connecting to and from needs to be a part of the same VPC.

Cloud Run doesn't currently support VPC access, so you'll need to use have a public IP for now, there's already a [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/146459086) to enable this kind of functionality.